# SQL Server show results where count of distinct columns higher than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to show aggregated results from a table like below but only when pair of the two columns (`TransactionType, ClientId`) is unique more than once.

My current query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(OrderQty), ClientId, OrderId 
FROM 
    Table 
GROUP BY 
    ClientId, TransactionType 
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(TransactionType, ClientId)) > 1
```

Output:

```
TransactionType  ClientId  Product  OrderQty
--------------------------------------------
123                A01     Apples     10
123                A22     Apples     20
222                A01     Book       20
222                A01     Car        20
555                A09     Book       20
555                A09     Oranges    20
999                A01     Apples     10
999                A22     Apples     20
```

Desired Output

```
TransactionType  ClientId  Product  OrderQty
--------------------------------------------
123                A01     Apples     10
123                A22     Apples     20
999                A01     Apples     10
999                A22     Apples     20
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your current query

Comment: Actually which is right - title of the question or desired output?

Comment: Sorry if I have confused you. I don't see my title and my desired output contradicting :( but the desired output is what I need. Maybe this should have been my question:
Give me only the aggregated results where the pair of (TransactionType,ClientId) is unique more than 1 time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a derived table similar to your current query, and join it to the original table for the results :

```
SELECT s.* FROM YourTable s
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.transactionType , t.product
            FROM YourTable t
            GROUP BY t.transactionType , t.product having COUNT(*) > 1) ss
 ON(s.transactionType = t.transactionType and s.product = t.product)
```

This will give you the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at desired output (which really contradicts the title).

```
SELECT ClientId,TransactionType, Min(OrderId) as OrderId, Min(OrderQty) as OrderQty
FROM Table 
GROUP BY ClientId,TransactionType 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    t.TransactionType,
    t.ClientId,
    t.Product,
    t.OrderQty
FROM
    Table t
JOIN
    (SELECT
        ClientId,
        TransactionType
    FROM
        Table
    GROUP BY
        ClientId,
        TransactionType
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) > 1) AS a
ON t.ClientId = a.ClientId
AND t.TransactionType = a.TransactionType
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Temp table with the example data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tbl') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Tbl 

SELECT A.* 
INTO #Tbl
FROM 
(
SELECT 123 TransactionType, 'A01' ClientId, 'Apples' Product, 10 OrderQty 
UNION SELECT 123,'A22','Apples',20
UNION SELECT 222,'A01','Book',20
UNION SELECT 222,'A01','Car',20
UNION SELECT 555,'A09','Book',20
UNION SELECT 555,'A09','Oranges',20
UNION SELECT 999,'A01','Apples',10
UNION SELECT 999,'A22','Apples',20
) A


-- Requested query

SELECT 
B.TransactionType
,B.ClientId
,B.Product
,B.OrderQty
FROM 
(
SELECT 
T.TransactionType
,T.ClientId
,T.Product
,T.OrderQty
,COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY T.TransactionType,T.ClientId) N
FROM #Tbl T
)
B
WHERE B.N = 1
```